# virtual wireless interface

Tags: wireless

I have one laptop with one physical wireless card. I need it to support two virtual wireless interface so that it support extra vlan, or one for lan the other in ad-hoc mode, using wireless. Is there any driver or software for this on windows and/or linux?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with 'iw'

Something like...

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add vwlan0 type managed
```

replacing wlan and vwlan0 as needed, you may also need to set a MAC manually which can be done with

```
sudo ip link set dev vwlan0 address 12:34:56:78:90:12
```

replacing the MAC with whatever you want, then you just

```
sudo ip link set dev vwlan0 up
```

and you should be able to manage it as needed.